# Unwanted GridView spacing in Android

Tags: android, gridview

I'm having a problem with spacing in Android while putting together a GridView. Essentially, I'm putting together a 9x9 gameboard. I've got a GridView working OK, but it's got unwanted spacing after each define square on the horizontal (vertical is OK) - so it doesn't fit the working area properly.

EDIT: It appears the GridView has allocated 50dp per square width, when I only want it to be 30dp... not sure why or how I can change it?

Custom grid code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class CustomGrid extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private final int[] Imageid;


    public CustomGrid(Context c, int[] Imageid) {
        mContext = c;
        this.Imageid = Imageid;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Imageid.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View grid;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {
            grid = new View(mContext);
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridsingle, null);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
            imageView.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
            imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[position]);
        } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
        }

        return grid;
    }
}
```

Main view excerpt:

```
public class Gameplay extends Activity {
GridView grid;

    int[] imageId = {
            R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square,
            R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square,
            R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square,
            R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square,
            R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square,
            R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square,
            R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square,
            R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square,
            R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square, R.drawable.square,R.drawable.square

    };
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gameplay);
 CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(Gameplay.this, imageId);
        grid=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid);
            grid.setAdapter(adapter);
            grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(Gameplay.this, "You Clicked x", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

gridview xml:

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <GridView
            android:numColumns="9"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:columnWidth="30dp"
            android:stretchMode="none"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/grid"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

imageview xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:padding="0dp" >


<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_image"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:stretchMode="none">
    </ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The end result comes out like this:
[image: test screen]

I've tried the obvious ideas like adjusting widths and using StretchMode parameters, but no luck as yet. Any ideas?

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: try set the width of the grid view to wrap content

Comment: Sadly that didn't work. Just to add to my question, it appears the GridView has allocated 50dp width per square, when I only want it to be 30dp...

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem - it turns out I had conflicting layouts for my gridview (id grid) - once I removed the derelict layout all started working!